# Issue with Express Entry Canada?

Tags: canada, express-entry

My wife and I are planning to apply for the Canadian Express entry pool, and we qualify as well. The issue that we are facing is that we both have different nationalities. We want to apply together and our funds are in my home country in a joint account.

Can my wife apply from a different country other than her home country or does she need to make a separate application from her home country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no separate application. If she is the main applicant, she just has to select a different current country of residence where she is currently residing. If you are the main applicant, then pretty much the same. When you fill out the forms, if gives you options to select *current country of residence* and *Nationality* as they are both two different things. Hope that helps.

Source: Have filled these forms myself.